# sklearn to pmml pipeline how to apply postprocessing linear trasnformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, pmml, sklearn2pmml

I'm having a tough time trying to apply a postprocessing step with the sklearn2pmml packages. What I'm trying to do is to apply a linear transformation after applying the predict_proba method within the PMMMLPipeline class in sklearn2pmml package. Any idea about how to do this?
Even a solution outside this package but automatable would help me (like modifying automatically the XML from the PMML).

Here's an example so you can get a deeper understanding of what I'm trying to do:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn2pmml import make_pmml_pipeline, sklearn2pmml

# FORGET ABOIT TRAIN TEST SPLIT; we only care if  the  PMML pipeline works for now 
BIRTHDAY_SEED = 1995
nrows, cols = 1000, 5
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=nrows, n_features=cols, n_informative=2, n_redundant=3, n_classes=2, shuffle=True, random_state=BIRTHDAY_SEED)
X, y = pd.DataFrame(X), pd.Series(y)
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)

def postprocessig_linear_transformation(probabilities, a,b):
    "This function would multiply proabilities by a and sum b"
    return probabilities*a+b

# the pipeline should look like this
# first predict probabilities
probabilities = model.predict_proba(X)[:,0]
# then scale them (apply linear transformation)
probabilities_scaled = postprocessig_linear_transformation(probabilities, a = 1000, b=100)

# of course it does not work,
pmml_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
    # here we should place the category preprocesor; I know it does not work but , so you can get the idea
  ('decisiontree',model),
    ('postprocesing_apply_linear_transformation',postprocessig_linear_transformation)
])
sklearn2pmml(pmml_pipeline, "example_pipeline_pmml.pmml", with_repr = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a second thought, you don't need a full-blown `LinearRegression` step to perform a deterministic `a * x + b` probability scaling operation. A simple `ExpressionTransformer` step is more than adequate:

```
from sklearn2pmml.preprocessing import ExpressionTransformer

pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("decisiontree", model)
], predict_proba_transformer = ExpressionTransformer("X[0] * 1000 + 100"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I did today, I was about to post the answer but you were faster haha.

Comment: If you need to scale multiple probability fields independently, then use a `FeatureUnion` wrapper to "make multiple ExpressionTransformers look like a single transformer".

Comment: Thanks! Don't need that for now; I guess now the pmml is fully functional, the only one thing that could be remaining if to know if I can use some target encoders directly, but that does not matter, with this I can automate it anyways. I guess the problem is I'm not very friend of the .pmmls for now nor the sklearn2pmml library. If you are the owner of the library, I would definitely suggest more docstring documentation. The library is nice btw!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having a tough time trying to apply a postprocessing step with the sklearn2pmml packages.

Don't blame the SkLearn2PMML package for your troubles. It is the Scikit-Learn framework that prohibits you from inserting two estimator objects into a single Pipeline object.

In the current case, you should rephrase your problem. What you're really trying to do is build a "chain of two models" (the first model feeding into the second model). The SkLearn2PMML package provides a `sklearn2pmml.ensemble.EstimatorChain` estimator type, which allows you to accomplish exactly that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I know sklearn is kinda prohibite, but no need to focus on that. I'm not blaming the package. I'm checking the package code here: https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml/blob/master/sklearn2pmml/ensemble/__init__.py in the EstimatorChain class, and the predict method actually calls only predicts and not predict_proba. I would need to call first predict_proba of my estimator; then apply  a linear transformation on those probas (would be DecisionTreee predict proba and then linear regression predict). The code does not support that :/

Comment: You can choose different predictions methods using `EstimatorChain.Link.augment_funcs` attribute. There is no dedicated `predict_proba` method, but the generated PMML will be fully functional.

Comment: This is a rather low-complexity task. Alternatively, it should be possible to handle it using the `sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier` estimator type.

Comment: The problem with sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier  is that if for example you use stacking_clf = StackingClassifier(estimators = [("dt",DecisionTreeClassifier() )],final_estimator =  linear_model) # assume linearmodel is fitted with coef required.  Then i get ValueError: 'final_estimator' parameter should be a classifier. Got LinearRegression() . As you said before, sklearn is very restrictive and we know that.